# Search engine using binary tree code c++ help please

Tags: c++, search

I am doing a project about search engine usinng binary tree.
I think there are a lot of problems. I tried so mush without any result
and I don't know how to call Btree in `main`, it gives me an error all the time.

I have a text file with int and string. It will be like this:

**1925  John Baird transmits the first television signal**

In this program I will search by the int year and give the information of what happend in that year.

**1-information class**

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    using 

namespace std;

class information{ 

private:

    int year;
    string data; 

public:

    information(int  year, string data);
    string getData();
    int getyear();
    void setData(string dat);
    void setYear(int yer);
};
```

**2- BinNode class**

```
 #include "information.h"
#include <iostream>
// Binary tree node ADT

template <typename Elem> class BinNode {

public:

virtual ˜BinNode() {}

    virtual void setEvent(const information&) = 0;
    virtual BinNode* left() const = 0;
    virtual void setLeft(BinNode*) = 0;
    virtual BinNode* right() const = 0;
    virtual void setRight(BinNode*) = 0;
    virtual bool isLeaf() = 0;
};
```

**3-BNode class**

```
   #include <iostream>
#include "BinNode.h"
#include "information.h"

using namespace std;

// Binary tree node implementation

template <typename Elem> 
class BNode: public BinNode<Elem> {

  private:

    information Event;

    BNode* lc;
    BNode* rc;
       public:
    BNode() { lc=rc=NULL;}
    BNode(information d, Bnode* l = NULL, 
               Bnode* r = NULL) {
        info = d;  lc = l; rc = r;
    }

        information getEvent(){
        return information.getEvent;

    }

     information setEvent(information e) {
         Event = e;
     }


    BNode* left() const {return lc;}

    void setLeft(BNode* b) {lc = b;}

    BNode* right() const {return rc;}
    a
    void setRight(BNode* b) {rc = b}

    bool isLeaf() {
        return (lc==NULL) && (rc==NULL);
    }
};
```

**4- BinaryTree class**

```
 #include <iostream>;

// Binary tree ADT

template <int> class BinaryTree {

  public:
    BinaryTree();

    virtual bool search() =0;
    virtual bool search() =0;
    virtual void insert() =0;
    virtual bool remove() = 0;
    virtual void fillTree() = 0


};
```

**5- BTree class**

```
  #include <iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include "BinaryTree.h"
#include "BNode.h"
#include "information.h"

using namespace std;

// Binary tree implementation

template <type Elem> class BTree: public BinaryTree<Elem> {

  private:
    BNode* root;

  public:
       BinaryTree() {root = NULL;}


  void insert(information i){

  BNode* current;

  BNode* trailCurrent;

  BNode* newNode;

  newNode = new BNode;

  newNode->Event= i;

  newNode->lc=NULL; newNode->rc=NULL;

  if (root == NULL)

     root = newNode;

  else{

     current = root;

     while(current!=NULL){

       trailCurrent = current;

       if (current->Event== i){

        cout<< “No duplicate allowed”;return;}

       else if (current->Event> key)

     current = current->lc;

       else current = current->rc;

     }
      if(trailCurrent->Event> i)

        trailCurrent->lc = newNode;

      else trailCurrent->rc = newNode;

  }
 }


  bool search(int key){

  Bnode* current;

  bool found = false;

  if (root == NULL)

     cout << "Empty Tree";

  else{
     current = root;

     while(current!= NULL && !found){

       if (current->Event.getYear() == key)

            found = true;

cout << "The IN FORMATION for " << key << " is " << curr->Event.getData() << endl;

else if (current->Event> key)

                current = current->lc;

       else current = current->rc;

     }
  }
}


  bool remove(information i){

  BNode* current;

  BNode* newNode;

  newNode = new BNode;

  newNode->Event= i;

  newNode->lc=NULL; newNode->rc=NULL;

     current = root;

     while(current!=NULL){

       if (current->Event== i){

           delete current;

       }
     }
  }

};
```

**6- main**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "BTree.h"
#include "information.h"
#include <fstream>
#include<string>

using namespace std;




int main(){

    BTree <>  b;    
    int ch;
    string data;
    int key,key2;
    int year;

    ifstream file;
    file.open("date.txt");
    if(!file) {
        cout<<" Error opening file. " << endl;
    }



    while(file >> year >> data)
    {


     year = file.get();
     p.setYear(year);  
     cout <<  p.getyear() << " ";
     getline ( file, data );
     p.setData(data);
     cout << p.getData() << endl;
     b.insert(p);
    }
    file.close();



    while(1)
    {
       cout<<" Binary Search Tree"<<endl;
       cout<<" 0. Search by year"<<endl;
       cout<<" 1. Search by tow year "<<endl;
       cout<<" 2. Exit "<<endl;
       cout<<" Enter your choice : ";
       cin>>ch;
       switch(ch)
       {
           case 0 : cout <<" Enter the year  to search : "<<endl;
                    cin>>key;
                    b.search(key);
                    break;

           case 1 : cout<<" Enter the first year: ";
                    cin>>key;
        cout<<" Enter the socend year: ";
        cin>>key2;
                   // b.search(key,key2);
                    break;

           case 2 : return 0;
       }
    }
};
```

Comment: you are going to have to whittle that down to where your problem actually lies if you expect to get any help.

Comment: I think would be more than a little surprised how much of this code is literally *not* needed *at all*, which in hindsight is probably a good thing, considering the portions of it that are just *wrong*. This is borderline as a case to better be served on [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) rather than here.

Comment: When you used your debugger, where does the issue occur?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see **a**  problem, The `Btree` class is reinitalizing the constructor to `BinaryTree`

It should be:

```
public:
   //BinaryTree() {root = NULL;}
   Btree() { }
```

The Derived class, by principle will call Base classes constructor.

**Another one:**

```
virtual bool search() =0;
```

is being declared twice.

**Another one:**

```
virtual void fillTree() = 0;
```

Requires you to define a `fillTree` function in your `Btree`(Derived) class. Or have it as an absolute virtual function in the `Derived` class, but then that means the class must not be initiated, and should Inherited by another `Dervied` class which defines the `virtual` function.

This [link](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/overview-virtual-fns.html) might help

Comment: thank you  about the search i am declared twicw because i will use tow search method the first with one parameter and the second with the two parameter